# Changing dataset XSD in VS2010 generates code inheriting from DataTable instead of TypedTableBase<Type>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, strongly-typed-dataset, linq-to-dataset, msdatasetgenerator

The current XSD is :

```
<xs:element name="Country">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="diallingcode" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="displayOrder" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="countryKey1">
        <xs:selector xpath="." />
        <xs:field xpath="mstns:code" />
    </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

And the generated class is:

```
[global::System.Serializable()]
    [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")]
    public partial class CountryDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<CountryRow> {
```

As soon as I modified the XSD, adding a new field. The generated class changes to:

```
[global::System.Serializable()]
    [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")]
    public partial class CountryDataTable : global::System.Data.DataTable, global::System.Collections.IEnumerable {
```

This last code breaks some Linq queries that are using the dataset.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: In what version of VS.NET or .NET was the original XSD generated?

Comment: VS 2005 and .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with datasets, but the SXD seems pretty plain so I don't know whether it depends on the version it was generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generation of code is not behaving properly yet (when updating an existing XSD). The way I've found to sort out the problem is deleting Dataset.Designer.cs file (or just renaming it) every time I want to make a change in the XSD. When the file is being generated from the scratch, the code is generated properly.